# How run a shiny app inside of a function?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I would like to run a function that has a shiny app inside, but I can't.

Running this example separately, I first remove column one from my input data frame; then I run shiny to change whatever is necessary in the data frame and, when I close the window, a new object is saved with the changes; and finally I create a new column in the data frame.

This is an example script, but I would like that, when executing the function, the shiny window opens and some things are changed in the data frame for the user interactively. Could someone help?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

my_function <- function(x){

  select <- x[,-1]

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
    rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # dummy dataframe
  df = select
  
  # convert it to a "rhansontable" object
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$myTable, {
    test_df = hot_to_r(input$myTable)
    assign('my_data_frame',test_df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    # browser() # uncomment for debugging
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

my_data_frame2 <- my_data_frame %>%
  mutate(new_column_test = "hello")

return(my_data_frame2)

}

my_function(mtcars)
```

Comment: if you just want to edit a table during an r session you could also simply use edit(df)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you almost made it you don't want to return anything but add the data simply using `assign`

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

myapp_function <- function(data) {
  
  ui <- basicPage(
    actionButton("quit", label = "Close"),
    actionButton("create", label = "Create copy"),
    textInput("name","Set dataframe name", value  = "my_data_frame"),
    rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(data)
    })

    observeEvent(input$create, {
      assign( input$name, hot_to_r(input$myTable), envir=.GlobalEnv)
    })

    observeEvent(input$quit,{
      stopApp()
    })
    
  }
  ## launch app
  shinyApp(ui, server,options=c(shiny.launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyPaneViewer))
}

## test
myapp_function(iris)
myapp_function(mtcars)
myapp_function(PlantGrowth)
```

I would suggest to create the `ui` and `server` outside of the `myapp_function` - otherwise it will become a very large function...also creating a function inside another function is not the best practise.